# jQuery attribute equals selector not working

Tags: jquery

I have some problem in using the jQuery attribute equals selector.

The HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>Country Living In</td>
    <td>
    <select class="FormInput" name="Country" id="Country">
    <option label="India" value="1" selected="selected">India</option>
    <option label="USA" value="2">USA</option>
    <option label="United Kingdom" value="3">United Kingdom</option>
    <option label="Australia" value="6">Australia</option>
    <option label="Malaysia" value="125">Malaysia</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

 <tr id="stateRow">
    <td>State</td>
    <td>
    <select class="FormInput" id="SelectState" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select State -</option>
    </select>
    <select class="FormInput" name="State" id="State">
        <option selected="selected" value="">- Select State -</option>
        <option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar</option>
        <option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
        <option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
        <option value="4">Assam</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr id="cityRow">
    <td>City</td>
    <td>
    <select class="FormInput" id="SelectCity" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
    </select>

    <div id="INDIA-cities">
    <select class="FormInput" id="INDIA-1" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="1">Car Nicobar</option>
        <option value="2">Port Blair</option>
        <option value="3">Rest of Andaman and Nicobar</option>
    </select>

    <select class="FormInput" id="INDIA-2" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="4">Adilabad</option>
        <option value="5">Anantapur</option>
        <option value="6">Chittoor</option>
    </select>
    <select class="FormInput" id="INDIA-3" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="29">Along</option>
        <option value="30">Anini</option>
        <option value="31">Bomdila</option>
      </select>

    <select class="FormInput" id="INDIA-4" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="46">Baksa</option>
        <option value="47">Barpeta</option>
        <option value="48">Bongaigaon</option>
        <option value="49">Chirang</option>
        <option value="50">Dhemaji</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <select class="FormInput" id="USA-City" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="664">Abilene</option>
        <option value="665">Akron</option>
        <option value="666">Albany</option>
        <option value="667">Albuquerque</option>
        <option value="668">Alexandria</option>
        <option value="867">Others</option>
    </select>

    <select class="FormInput" id="UK-City" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="868">Cambridge</option>
        <option value="869">London</option>
        <option value="870">Liverpool</option>
        <option value="871">Manchester</option>
        <option value="876">Others</option>
    </select>

    <select class="FormInput" id="AUSTRALIA-City" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="877">Sydney</option>
        <option value="878">Melbourne</option>
        <option value="879">Brisbane</option>
        <option value="880">Perth</option>
        <option value="881">Others</option>
    </select>

    <select class="FormInput" id="MALAYSIA-City" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="882">Subang Jaya</option>
        <option value="883">Kuala Lumpur</option>
        <option value="884">Klang</option>
        <option value="885">Johor Bahru</option>
        <option value="886">Ampang Jaya</option>
        <option value="887">Others</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
 </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var stateRow = $("#stateRow"),
        cityRow = $("#cityRow"),
        SelectState = $("#SelectState"),
        SelectCity = $("#SelectCity"),
        State = $("#State"),
        Country = $("#Country"),
        USAcity = $("#USA-City"),
        UKcity = $("#UK-City"),
        AUSTRALIAcity = $("#AUSTRALIA-City"),
        MALAYSIAcity = $("#MALAYSIA-City");    

    Country.change(function() {
        var sCountry = $(this).val();
        stateRow.hide();
        SelectState.hide();
        SelectCity.hide();
        cityRow.hide();
        $('#INDIA-cities').hide();
        State.hide().attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        $('#INDIA-cities select').each(function(){
            //this.id = this.id + "_" + i;
            $(this).attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        USAcity.hide().attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        UKcity.hide().attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        AUSTRALIAcity.hide().attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        MALAYSIAcity.hide().attr({
                name: '',
                disabled: true
            });
        });

        if(sCountry=="1") {
            stateRow.show();
            State.show().attr({
                name: 'State',
                disabled: false
            });
            cityRow.show();
            SelectCity.show();
        }
        else if(sCountry=="2") {
            cityRow.show();
            USAcity.show().attr({
                name: 'City',
                disabled: false
            });
        }
        else if(sCountry=="3") {
            cityRow.show();
            UKcity.show().attr({
                name: 'City',
                disabled: false
            });
        }
        else if(sCountry=="6") {
            cityRow.show();
            AUSTRALIAcity.show().attr({
                name: 'City',
                disabled: false
            });
        }
        else if(sCountry=="125") {
            cityRow.show();
            MALAYSIAcity.show().attr({
                name: 'City',
                disabled: false
            });
        }
    });

    State.change(function() {
        sState = $(this).val();
        $('#INDIA-cities').hide();
        var len = this.length;
        if(sState != '')
        {
            SelectCity.hide();
            $('#INDIA-cities').show();
            for(i=1;i<=len;i++){
                var citylist = $("#INDIA-"+i);
                if (sState != $(this[i]).val()) {
                    citylist.hide().attr('name','');
                }
                else
                {
                    citylist.show().attr({
                        name: 'City',
                        disabled: false
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SelectCity.show();
            for(i=1;i<=len;i++){
                var citylist = $("#INDIA-"+i);
                citylist.hide().attr('name','');
            }
        }
    });

    State.blur(function(){
            if($(this).val()=='')
            {
                alert("Select State");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

    });

    $("#cityRow").find('select[name="City"]').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val()=='')
            {
                alert("Select City");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

    });
});
```

When the 'City' dropdown is enabled and is empty, then an alert box should pop out saying 'Select City', on blur of the 'City' dropdown. But its not showing up.

The above code is available live at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prajan55/CwPTZ/).

Kindly help me in solving the issue..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, any suggestion on trimming down the above script is helpful.

Comment: You should be using ajax for this kinda of things, as this would be easier to manage through ajax, can validate each entry on the fly on serverside, and you don't need as much code in one page, you can split them up, so in the future you'd find the right data quicker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because none of the selects have the name attribute set to the City when the code is run. Change it to use live binding like this and it should work:

```
$("#cityRow").find('select[name="City"]').live('blur', function(){
```

Comment: .live is not needed, as he is not expecting dynamic elements to be added there.

Comment: The attribute he is selecting on is being dynamically changed though. The other way would be to bind on all selects and then check the attribute in the handler.

Answer (score 2):

You have used

```
$("#cityRow").find('select[name="City"]').blur(function(){
```

and then looking at your html you have

```
<select class="FormInput" id="INDIA-1" name="" style="display:none">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Select City -</option>
        <option value="1">Car Nicobar</option>
        <option value="2">Port Blair</option>
        <option value="3">Rest of Andaman and Nicobar</option>
    </select>
```

Where the `name=""` should be `name="City"`

That said you should really be using classes as [name="City"] is not pretty :), lets say you need to change the name tag later on for whatever reasons to match that of your serverside validations, or even mysql in some cases, you would have to change everything again, where as class do not have to change :)

Comment: Thank u Val, for your suggestion to use ajax serverside validation. I would give it a try for sure.